# Trouble making my pie chart smaller

Tags: html, css

I've created a pie chart using only HTML5 and CSS3, and it works perfectly. The problem however, is that I made the pie too big.

What I want is for the pie to be about 50% - 75% of it's current size. How should I do this?

Here's the JSFiddle; [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/3ptagxuv/1/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div id="PieChartLeft">
        <div class="pie"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="PieChartLeftValue">
        <div class="pie"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pie {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px; 
    border-radius:100px; 
}

#PieChartLeft, #PieChartLeftValue {
    -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(270deg); 
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,100px);
    left:300px;
}

#PieChartLeft .pie {
    background-color:salmon;
    border-color:salmon;
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg); 
    transform:rotate(180deg); 
}

#PieChartLeftValue .pie {
    background-color:grey;
    border-color:grey;
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Do you want this to be responsive? You could just adjust the values, or use the padding-hack.

Comment: @KreaTief, preferably, yes.

Comment: Okay, I will write you a demo, should be fairly simple

Comment: okay, just checked your code. You use clip for your chart, which means it is impossible to use percentages. I will try and find out if there is another way of making a pie chart, that supports percentages

Comment: @KreaTief, don't worry. (: I already got it! I put it in an answer.

Comment: I still did, was bothering me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got it, turns out I just had to change this;

```
.pie {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px; 
    border-radius:100px; 
}
```

Into this:

```
.pie {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    clip:rect(0px,75px,150px,0px);
    -moz-border-radius:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius:100px; 
    border-radius:75px; 
}
```

In other words, lower the width & height to whatever I want, then edit the second value in the clip:rect() to half of the width and the 3rd value to the value of height.
Then the border-radius to half the width.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will make the chart smaller, if you want to make your chart fluid though, you will use a different approach.
I wrote you a codepen about it.
Just change the variable `$width`to whatever percentage value you want, then click on the eye on the top to see the compiled css.

http://codepen.io/bekreatief/pen/liHBs